# How to use .find method on users from DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, authentication

I'm trying create User Authentication system and I'm stuck at verifying user, mainly because I don't understand how can I go through ALL MY USERS to filter (.find) out usernames and compare them to username I'm trying to login with.

This line of code creating error, it doesn't see values (all users I saved) in Users:

```
const usernameCheck = Users.find(x => x.username = req.body.username);
```

Code to verify user:

```
router.route('/login').post(async (req, res) => {
    const usernameCheck = Users.find(x => x.username = req.body.username);
    if (usernameCheck === null) {
        return res.status(400).send('Cannot find user');
    } 
    try {
       if (await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, usernameCheck.password)){
           res.send('Success')
       } else {
           res.send('Not allowed!')
       }
    } catch {
        res.status(500).send()
    }
});
```

I create new users in "Users" like that, according to mongoose schema I created:

```
router.route('/add').post(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10); // 10 is const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt/*10 is default*/);
        const email = req.body.email;
        const username = req.body.username;
        const password = hashedPassword;
        const IP = req.connection.remoteAddress;

        const newUser = new Users({
            email,
            username,
            password,
            IP
        });
        newUser.save()
            .then(() => res.json('User added!'))
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
    } catch {
        res.status(500).send()
    }
   
});
```

So how can I go through all my created users using .find method?

Comment: i think its equality check and it should be `==` not `=` ryt in here `const usernameCheck = Users.find(x => x.username = req.body.username);`

Comment: I get this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of null" so shouldn't be a problem with ```=```

Comment: might be but yet it will become an assignment ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with your syntax, I usually do something like this:

```
Users.findOne({username: req.body.username}, 'username', (err, result) => {
    if(err) {
        throw err
    }
    if(!result) {
        return res.status(400).send('Cannot find user');
    }
    // your verification
}
```

Comment: By 'username' you mean those usernames I have stored in DB?

Comment: 'username' is the name of your column